# JOptionPane.showInputDialog does not open dialog box

Tags: java, eclipse, joptionpane

I was able to use this code successfully until yesterday, but after that JOptionPane.showInputDialog does not launch the dialog box, be it any simple code.

I use 64 bit system and code was working fine.

I have tried reinstalling Java, selenium, eclipse but nothing helped..I seem to have been missing very small thing. it will be great help if anyone can tell what exactly am I missing.

Here is my code (however any simple code is not working)

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    String[] choices = { 
            "Belk-Make New Config Changes", 
            "Belk-Bring Back to Original", 
            "JCP-Make New Config Changes", 
            "JCP-Bring Back to Original"};
    System.out.println(choices);
    String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
            "What do you want to do...",
            "SyPi Config Changes", 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
            null,  // use default icon
            choices, // Array of choices
            choices[0]); // Initial choice
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting it as visible?

Comment: Just copied and ran it on my machine, no problems with the code. Check your run target.

Comment: Can you please tell how to make it visible...